# Anticommuting sets of Dirac $\gamma$-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, clifford-algebras

At the end of this [webpage](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiracMatrices.html), it is said that there exist 6 maximal anticommuting sets each consisting of 5 Dirac $\gamma$-matrices. I couldn't find anything more in the book cited there, either.

But what is the relation between these 6 sets? Are they related by unitary transformations or else?
For example, we can think of the following to sets.
$$\alpha_0=\sigma_z\otimes\tau_z,\alpha_1=\sigma_x\otimes\tau_0,\alpha_2=\sigma_y\otimes\tau_0,\alpha_3=\sigma_z\otimes\tau_x,\alpha_4=\sigma_z\otimes\tau_y$$
$$\beta_0=\sigma_z\otimes\tau_0,\beta_1=\sigma_x\otimes\tau_z,\beta_2=\sigma_y\otimes\tau_0,\beta_3=\sigma_x\otimes\tau_x,\beta_4=\sigma_x\otimes\tau_y$$